# Run a method from form 1 to run in form 2 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, methods

I have two forms. Form one (mainForm) has a listview with a method called on loading the form to populate the list (private sub populateUsers) with users from a database . This works perfectly. I have a button on the form that opens a second form while keeping the first form open (required for the program) to add new users (newUserForm). When the user is saved to the database via a button in the new user form, this form is hidden. The problem is trying to call the method from form one via a button in form two to repopulate the list and add the new user.
I have searched for an answer but no luck. Any ideas?
Thanks
P.S. I have tried assigning form 1 to a variable in form 2 but this doesn't work. I have tried to directly use the method when pressing the button but no luck. I have tested it with a messagebox function so form 2 is able to use methods from form 1.

Comment: It is the first form that owns the listview and knows how to populate it. Don't confuse things. Show the newUserForm modally and then, on exit from that form (with an OK as DialogResult) repopulate the list from inside the first form.

Comment: What do you mean by modally? Im still learning VB.net as im a student so i have not heard this term before. I do understand what else you are saying though. Thanks.

Comment: When you open the newUserForm use _newUserForm.ShowDialog()_ then, inside that form, set, to the OK button, the DialogResult property equals to OK. Now the form closes automatically when you press the OK button and you get the DialogResult.OK as return from the previous ShowDialog call

Comment: Some basic info here https://joebuschmann.com/best-practices-for-creating-and-consuming-modal-dialogs-in-winforms/ It is in C# but the rules are the same for VB.NET

Comment: Thats a big help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one :

```
 Public Sub  '.......................... (Name of your event like on_click)
       My.Forms.Form2.MethodName 'Replace method name with your method name
 End Sub
```